# Infer $Tf=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f,f_n) f_n$ from frame condition.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

A sequence of distinct vectors $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$ belonging to a separable Hilbert space $H$ is said to be a Frame if there exist positive contants $A$, $B$ such that, for $A<B$ and for all $f\in H$ (*frame condition*):
$$A\|f\|^2\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2\leq B \|f\|^2 \ \ \ \ (\ast)$$
An operator $T$ on $H$ is said "frame operator" of frame $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$, if
$$Tf=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f,f_n) f_n \ \ \ \ \ \ (\ast\ast)$$
By this the $(\ast)$ becomes,
$$A\|f\|^2\leq (Tf,f)\leq B \|f\|^2 \ \ \ \ \ (\ast\ast\ast)$$
My question is the following. In general, isn't possible infer $(\ast\ast)$ by $(\ast\ast\ast)$ but... are there some conditions for which it is possible? Maybe for $f$ in a dense subset of $H$?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. However, $(***)$ is a condition that the operator $T$ defined in $(**)$ should satisfy, i.e., $(***)$ does not define an operator, but are conditions that an operator can satisfy. To be precise, condition $(***)$ yields that the frame operator is a linear, bounded bijection.